# AVAudioEngine() Playback Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to change the pitch of a sound using the `AVAudioEngine()` in Swift. This is my code:

```
func setUpEngine() {
    let fileString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("400", ofType: "wav")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileString!)
    do {
        try audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
        print("done")
    }
    catch{

    }
}
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
var audioFile = AVAudioFile()
var audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var changeAudioUnitTime = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    setUpEngine()
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    audioPlayerNode.stop()
    engine.stop()
    engine.reset()
    engine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)
    changeAudioUnitTime.pitch = 800
    engine.attachNode(changeAudioUnitTime)
    engine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: changeAudioUnitTime, format: nil)
    engine.connect(changeAudioUnitTime, to: engine.outputNode, format: nil)
    audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    engine.startAndReturnError(nil)
    audioPlayerNode.play()
```

The rest of my code is below (I do close the brackets).
I found most of this code online and I get an error with the line

```
engine.startAndReturnError(nil)
```

> 'Value of type has no member'.

When I remove this line I get the following error:

> 'AVAudioPlayerNode.mm:333: Start: required condition is false:
>   _engine->IsRunning() Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false:
>   _engine->IsRunning()''

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Swift in xCode and a single view application.

Answer (score 4):

The error is that the engine is not running. You need to reorder your operations like this...

```
setUpEngine()
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
engine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)
engine.attachNode(changeAudioUnitTime)
engine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: changeAudioUnitTime, format: nil)
engine.connect(changeAudioUnitTime, to: engine.outputNode, format: nil)
changeAudioUnitTime.pitch = 800
engine.prepare()    
engine.start()    
audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
audioPlayerNode.play()
```

Some time later...

```
engine.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are running on either outdated version of XCode or incompatible version of iOS. I had this issue and in the latest Swift version there is no such method instead they provide .start().

Comment: incompatible version of iOS was for me